# elm-mode can't compile file

Tags: compilation

When creating projects with `elm init`, elm creates a project structure where there is a `elm.json` in the root of the project directory and a `src` folder, where your .elm files [should go](https://elm-lang.org/0.19.0/init)

[Elm-mode](https://github.com/jcollard/elm-mode) for emacs doesn't seem to support this. When visiting a file in the `src` directory and typing `C-c C-c` to compile the file, I get the following error:

```
-*- mode: elm-compilation; default-directory: "~/Projects/select-elm/src/" -*-
Elm-Compile started at Mon May 13 04:29:55

/home/chris/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.3/bin/elm make Main.elm --output\=elm.js
-- FILE NOT FOUND --------------------------------------------------------------

You want me to compile this file:

    Main.elm

I cannot find it though! Is there a typo?


Elm-Compile exited abnormally with code 1 at Mon May 13 04:29:56
```

This is the same error you get when calling `elm make Main.elm` from the command line in the `src` folder instead of in the root folder of the project.

If this same file is saved to the root folder of the project, `C-c C-c` compiles the file without errors. It seems `elm-mode` expects source files to be directly in the root directory of a project, while the elm language convention is to save the source files in the `src` folder.

I'm using elm 0.19.0. Is there a graceful way to make elm-mode "project aware", or something similar?

Unfortunately I don't have the option of simply saving my files to the root folder of the project because this is not a project that I own.

Comment: Are you calling the right compile function? By default, `C-c C-c` is bound to `elm-compile-buffer`, which basically runs `elm make <filename of current buffer>` in the current directory. `C-c M-c` is bound to `elm-compile-main` which will basically run `elm make Main.elm` _in the current directory_, even if `Main.elm` isn't there.

Comment: If that's not the case, your project style just might not jive with `elm-mode`. You can see what `elm-mode` settings you can customize (`M-x customize-mode RET elm`), or you can file an issue with the `elm-mode` developers. Be explicit with how your project is set up, and help you with customization, or add the features you need.

Comment: C-c M-c warns me "Elm package file not found. Create a new package file? (yes or no)". When I answer "yes", the command fails with "Opening input file: No such file or directory, ~/Projects/select-elm/src/elm-package.json". Re-running C-c M-c and answering "no" doesn't produce anything useful either.

Comment: As far as my "project style" goes, it's actually that of elm, i.e. what `elm init` created, which is why I'm confused; elm and elm-mode seem to have divergent notions of their project structure. Looking at the sources, I also saw that elm-mode does a lot with `default-directory`, which when you're visiting a file is the directory the file resides in. This is why I mentioned "project aware" above. I'm still  debugging though and will report back.

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while to figure this one out, posting to help future users.

Elm-mode uses by default `"elm-package.json"` to find the root directory of your project. This was the value used in Elm 0.18 and changed in 0.19 to `"elm.json"`.

Just customize the variable `elm-package-json` and set it to `"elm.json"`.

For example `(setq elm-package-json "elm.json")`

This is described in `elm-util.el`